# Rich globbing `ls [G-S]*` in fish shell?

Tags: linux, shell, fish

In Bash it is possible to

```
ls [G-S]*
```

and it would list all files from `g-s` and `G-S`.

How is that done in Fish shell?

Comment: `[G-S]` doesn't list `g*` (at least under `en_US.UTF-8` and `cs_CZ.UTF-8`).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fish currently does not support a rich glob syntax. The current thinking is that a `glob` command should be added in keeping with the fish goal of doing things via commands rather than magic syntax. See, for example, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3681. The solution is to create a function that filters the results. For example, the `**` glob matches all files and directories in and below the CWD. I frequently want just the plain files and want to ignore the `.git` subdir. So I wrote this function:

```
function ff --description 'Like ** but only returns plain files.'
    # This also ignores .git directories.
    find . \( -name .git -type d -prune \) -o -type f | sed -n -e '/\/\.git$/n' -e 's/^\.\///p'
end
```

Which I can then use like this: `grep something (ff)`. You could create a similar function that uses the `find -name` pattern matching feature or filter the results with `string match --regex`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find -iregex "./[G-S].*"`. Fish is quite limited in this regard.